# How to upload multiple pictures at once in itunesconnect?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

How can I upload multiple pictures at once to my app details in itunesconnect? I remember that at some time it was possible via Safari and drag/dropping multiple pictures onto the 'choose picture'-button. Now (Mountain Lion, Safari 6.0.1) it isn´t anymore.

Any ideas on how to solve this? It´s really annoying to upload 15 pictures (iPhone, iPhone5, iPad) one after another.

Answer (score 0):

I not sure if it was ever possible to upload multiple pictures at once. However, drag & drop (for single files) is still possible - it's just broken in Safari, which opens/displays the dragged file. In Firefox and Chrome, dropping an image file (e.g. some .png) on the "Choose File" button results in an upload.

Comment: Thanks, but the topic is uploading _multiple_ pictures.

Comment: @stk: I know that. Like I said, I don't remember ever being able to upload multiple pictures. I also couldn't find any documentation that supports your statement that this DID work at some point. So my answer is: It is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that as i have tried up to 2 images

Answer (score 0):

Seems like apple removed this feature, for whatever reason.
Best you make a suggestion on iTunes Connect.
Just log in and click on "Contact Us" in the footer.

(I can't provide a link, because it varies)

Comment: Well...you can click on 'contact us', but there will never be any link to send them a real message. It´s all more like a FAQ.

Comment: Choose 'iTunes Connect Functionality Question' and then 'General iTunes Connect Inquiry'